# How to count results in a join query

Tags: mysql

```
select music.*
 ,count(*) as count
FROM music
  JOIN music_tagmap ON music.id = music_tagmap.music_id
  JOIN tag ON music_tagmap.tag_id=tag.id
   WHERE tag.content = ...
   LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

To count the result, I first came up with adding line 2, but adding line 2 only return one row of the results and the count. How to get both of the results and the count in conditions like this?

Comment: Are you looking to get the total number of rows matched by the query (aside from the limit)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to:

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS music.*
FROM music
  JOIN music_tagmap ON music.id = music_tagmap.music_id
  JOIN tag ON music_tagmap.tag_id=tag.id
   WHERE tag.content = ...
   LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

and then run a second query after it's finished:

```
select FOUND_ROWS();
```

That will give you the number of rows selected in the first query as if there was no LIMIT statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off just doing a second query to get the count.  You could try embedding a "SELECT COUNT()" subquery in place of "count(*) as count)", but I don't think you're going to reduce the overhead a lot by embedding the subquery...it may even increase processing overhead.